# How to keep refreshing a page until it loads?

Tags: connection

I am trying to access a web-service that is currently very popular. Because of that I get a default browser message that says it could not connect.

Is there an application, or special browser, or browser plugin I could use to keep resending my request until I get a connection (brute force my way in the site)?

Comment: As an aside: note that *refreshing* often makes a browser request *all* content again. (More precisely: it will ask the server if cached content is indeed still valid, using `If-Modified-Since` headers. The server might then respond saying the cache is still good, but it *does* need a request to get that confirmation.) Hence, if a server is very slow, it's often better to click the location bar (or hit Ctrl-L) and hit Return, or click some link or a bookmark, instead of using refresh (like Ctrl-R or F5).

Comment: Caution: Don't be a part of the problem.  Give the site a chance to recover by setting your refresh to a large number.  Setting it to small > 60 seconds just compounds the sites troubles.

Answer (score 2):

[Reload Every](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/) is a plugin for Firefox which can do this.

Comment: Unfortunately it keeps reloading even after the page has successfully loaded :-(

Comment: Broken link. maybe the extension does not exist anymore?

Answer (score 2):

For Chrome: 
[Auto Refresh Plus](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oilipfekkmncanaajkapbpancpelijih)

Just have to watch it closely.

Comment: I tried this, but it ends up refreshing when the page has successfully loaded and not when it hasn't, which is the reverse of the desired behavior :-(

Answer (score 1):

Opera has an auto refresh option. If you use Firefox there is an addon called [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/). F4 also works to refresh pages.

Answer (score 1):

[TryAgain](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tryagain/) refreshes page when server cannot be reached.

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon for Firefox called ReloadEvery. It is a nice tool that has proven helpful to me many times. Opera also has this capability integrated into the browser with an option I think.

Comment: If Jonas uses ReloadEvery at say 1s intervals and wanders off for two minutes to get a coffee, his browser may have sent 120 requests got 60 successful pages and 60 "site busy" messages. Apart from the crippling effect this has on an overloaded site, does ReloadEvery stop when it gets a 200 response or will it just replace that a second later with a "site busy" response?

Comment: I don't know. I'm sure that simple google-ing could figure that out, but I have only used it for small spurts at a time @RedGrittyBrick.